# Is there a reliable way to scope Ninject bound services to an NServicebus message handler?

Tags: ninject, nservicebus

I want to bind my Entity Framework context to be scoped per NServicebus message. Would the following code successfully do that?

```cs
Bind<IDbContext>().To<MyContext>()
    .InScope(x => x.Kernel.Get<IBus>().CurrentMessageContext.Id);
```

**Background**

I have a NServicebus service that has several IMessageHandlers that read IEvents off an MSMQ Queue.

Each handler converts the message and saves it to a MS SQL Database by way of a particular IRepository sitting over an Entity Framework context.

The repositories needed by each handler are injected via ninject using NServicebus.ObjectBuilder.Ninject

```cs
public class Product
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class SampleContext : IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<Product> Products { get; }
    IDbSet<Category> Categories{ get; }
}

public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private IDbContext _context;
    public ProductRepository(IDbContext ctx) { _context = ctx; }

    public void Add(Product p)
    {
        _context.Products.Add(p);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class CategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
{
    private IDbContext _context;
    public CategoryRepository (IDbContext ctx) { _context = ctx; }

    public Category GetByCode(string code)
    {
        return _context.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == code);
    }
}

public class AddProductMessageHandler : IMessageHandler<IAddProductEvent>
{
    private IProductRepository _products;
    private ICategoryRepository _categories;
    public AddProductMessageHandler(IProductRepository p, ICategoryRepository c)
    {
        _products = p;
        _categories = c;
    }

    public void Handle(IAddProductEvent e)
    {
        var p = new Product();
        p.Code = e.ProductCode;
        p.Category = _categories.GetByCode(e.CategoryCode);
        _products.Add(p);
    }
}
```

**Issue**

If the EF context is bound in Transient scope (default) then each bound repository in the handler has it's own instance of the context.

```cs
Bind<IDbContext>().To<SampleContext>();
```

This causes issues if I load an object from one repository and then save it via another.

Likewise, if it's bound in Singleton scope, then the same context is used by all repositories, but then it slowly fills up with tracked changes and goobles up all my ram (and gets slower and slower to boot).

```cs
Bind<IDbContext>().To<SampleContext>().InSingletonScope();
```

**Question**

Ideally I would like each message handler to have 1 EF context that all required repositories (of that handler) use to load and save entities.

Is scoping the context to the current messages Id property a safe/reliable/good way of doing this?

```cs
Bind<IDbContext>().To<SampleContext>()
    .InScope(x => x.Kernel.Get<IBus>().CurrentMessageContext.Id);
```

Answer (score 2):

See my blogpost here which describes the scoping apart from NSB 4.0

http://www.planetgeek.ch/2013/01/16/nservicebus-unitofworkscope-with-ninject/

If you have 3.0 you can look into the current develop branch and port the extension methods to your code. You only have to change the scope name.

Comment: I had seen your post but as we are using Ninject 3.0.1.10, I don't have access to one of the required methods:
`IBindingInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<T> WhenNoAncestorNamed(string name);`

Comment: Ok. Pretty easy to program the method. You can copy paste it to your project from the GH repo with apache2 license header until you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with EF Context so please disregard if the answer below does not make any sense.

If EF Context is similar to a NH ISession, then I think the better option is to use a UoW the same way as [NH implementation](https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/master/src/nhibernate/UnitOfWork/NServiceBus.UnitOfWork.NHibernate/UnitOfWorkManager.cs).
You can read more about UoW [here](http://support.nservicebus.com/customer/portal/articles/860275-unit-of-work-in-nservicebus).

Comment: An Entity Framework context is essentially a unit of work.
I didn't delve into them too much, as I didn't really want to reference NServicebus (to get IManageUnitsOfWork) in my DataStore project.